# applying gradient fill to an object on the stage ..?

Tags: flash, actionscript

let's say i have this object on stage and it is called `myShape` and i want to manipulate it via action-script and apply a gradient color to it .. 
no if it is a fill color i could have used the `colortransform` method but i don't think that it will work .. and please don't suggest me to draw the shape with action script .

```
 import flash.geom.*
 import flash.display.*
 var fillType:String = GradientType.LINEAR;
 var colors:Array = [0xFF0000, 0x0000FF];
 var alphas:Array = [1, 1];
 var ratios:Array = [0x00, 0xFF];
 var matr:Matrix = new Matrix();
 matr.createGradientBox(200, 100, 0, 0, 0);
 var spreadMethod:String = SpreadMethod.PAD;
 myShape.graphics.beginGradientFill(fillType, colors, alphas, ratios, matr, spreadMethod);
```

now when i test this i don't get any errors but i doesn't apply any thing ..

Comment: is this question so hard or what ? .. lol

Comment: if it wasn't you would have found the solution by yourself :p

Comment: i really searched this subject a lot ..not being a geek but this is really a stupid thing to have a research about .. but it is also a stupid thing to have in action script 3 or isn't it ?.
and im still waiting for an answer .. lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create a bounding rectangle Shape, fill it with the gradient and apply the object as a mask. Is it possible in your case?

Comment: as you are suggesting a work around .. then I'd guess that there is no way around that .. but if there isn't any way around it then why did nobody tell me that .. ?!! thanks for your answer but I'm really thinking about this to have some extra knowledge . or outher wise i would have applied the gradient to the shape from flash .

Comment: I'm not talking about Flash, I'm talking about pure AS3 :)

Comment: you know what .. some times in lack of answers even "i don't know" counts as one .. but come on you've been a great help .. :) thanks for your time (and you came by this question again .. it seems like your a geek too lol !)